# Como abrir webcam en fullscreen con python?

Tags: python

tengo este código básico para abrir mi webcam vía python, pero no se cómo ponerlo en *fullscreen*, ¿me podrían ayudar?.

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con el parametro para FULLSCREEN que se llama `cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN` en `namedWindow` y `setWindowProperty`

```
cv2.namedWindow("Foo" , cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)    
cv2.setWindowProperty("Foo" ,
                      cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
                      cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

Puedes buscar aqui [Windows Property Flags](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ggabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3a78bc64121f612562bbb2fa23d316e84e)
En el apartado Python